# SQL Server 2008 UTC Conversion to EST

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, utc

I need to convert one date column hat the in the database dates are off by exactly 5 hours.the time is kept as UTC and when they one views it app it displays the EST time zone. The app converts the time automatically.  UTC is ahead of Eastern Standard Time by 5 . The following code seems to fix the time and day for most timestamps however , is there a way to set and offset ?  The report looks at one day back and should return the converted UTC to EST times.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Encounters.EncounterNo, MedicalRecords.MedRecNo as MRN,
    DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(hh, DATEDIFF(hh, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), Documents.CreateDateTime)) AS [Create Date],
    SUBSTRING(Enrollees.EnrolleeName, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Enrollees.EnrolleeName) - 1) as [Last Name],
    SUBSTRING(Enrollees.EnrolleeName, CHARINDEX(',', Enrollees.EnrolleeName) + 1, len(Enrollees.EnrolleeName)) as [First Name], 
    DocTypes.DocTypeName, 
    CAST(Enrollees.BirthDate AS Date) AS [BIRTH DATE], 
    Enrollees.Gender, Enrollees.SocSecNo, Enrollees.Address, 
    CAST(Encounters.EncntrStartDate AS Date) AS [ADMIT DATE]
FROM            
    Enrollees 
INNER JOIN
    MedicalRecords ON Enrollees.EnrolleeOwnerId = MedicalRecords.EnrolleeOwnerId 
INNER JOIN
    Documents 
INNER JOIN
    DocTypes ON Documents.DocType = DocTypes.DocType 
INNER JOIN
    DocsOwners ON Documents.DocId = DocsOwners.DocId 
INNER JOIN
    Encounters ON DocsOwners.OwnerId = Encounters.EncntrOwnerId 
    ON MedicalRecords.MedRecOwnerId = Encounters.MedRecOwnerId
WHERE
    Documents.DocType = '65' 
    AND (DATEDIFF(DD, GETUTCDATE(), Documents.CreateDateTime) = - 1)
ORDER BY 
    DocTypes.DocTypeName
```

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic643108-8-1.aspx

You may have to take into account day light saving time too.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/5435096c-7b7a-4d8a-8933-ab3b987f2b21/date-conversion-utc-to-est-with-day-light-saving

Comment: What kind of report consumes this query? It may be much easier to return the raw UTC times (minus one day) then perform the timezone conversion in the report, similar to how it's done in your app.

Comment: Hi Esoteric can you please post a sample line of code, also if I want to run the report based on a day back of this column time stamp how can I write this?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to accomplish this is to create a caluated column and then get the report to reference this new column.  This way you can keep your original data and still handle the conversion via the database.

```
ALTER TABLE [Your Table Name] ADD
UTC2EST  AS dateadd(hh,-5,[Your current UTC datetime column])
```

Comment: What if I want to run the report based on the previous day of the the Converted field - 1 ?

Comment: I would handle that in the stored procedure's where clause that supports the report.  Something like Where SomeDate = DateAdd(dd,-1,MyDate)